# Does the phrase “se lever et vivre” actually mean get up / stand up and live?

Tags: choix-de-mot, ordre-des-mots, questions, france, phrase

I feel like I’m making up a phrase with my limited, but growing, French Language abilities.

A direct translation on google translate does appear to carry the meaning that I intend: Loosely, “Get up and live” or more specifically, “Get up / Stand up for yourself and live your life.” But is this actually the case or would it be confusing to the native French speaker?

Comment: No native speaker. Here is my two cents. I would say something like : "leve-toi et vis ta vie".

Comment: Specifically, are you asking about "Get up, Stand Up" by Bob Marley and The Wailers? I've heard it translated as « Lève-toi, debout » et « Lève-toi, tiens debout ».

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference if the original sentence is "Get up and live" or "Stand up for yourself and live your life".

If it's the former, Dimitris' answered it correctly, and I agree with him on the "strong" feeling around it.

If it's the latter, it would be closer to something like:

> Affirme-toi et vis ta vie.

Which makes more sense than litterally standing up. Depending on [references](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/translation/standing+up+for+yourself.html), it could also be translated as *Défends-toi* or *Ne te laisse pas marcher sur les pieds*, the idea still being the same.

Comment: +1. Bravo for this excellent answer.

Comment: Selon le contexte, je proposerais aussi "assume-toi et vis ta vie".

Comment: @Adrien Oui, j'aime bien cette suggestion également, par exemple dans le contexte d'un "Tanguy" ou de quelqu'un qui vit au crochet de quelqu'un d'autre.

Answer (score 0):

I am neither native speaker of English nor of French. Here's my two cents if I understood correctly the desired idea in English (at least of the "Get up and live" part; cf. the much more elaborated answer of @Reydey). I would say something like:

> "Leve-toi et vis ta vie !"

with a higher intonation.